# How to use UIView as inverted mask for another UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Applying a `UIView` as mask to another `UIView` is no problem.

```
let view = UIView(...) 
let mask = UIView(...) 
view.mask = mask
```

Now only those parts of `view` will be visible where the `mask` view is also visible. **However, how can this be inverted?** I would like `view` to visible where `mask` is **NOT** visible. **How can I do this?**

While I found several solutions to invert paths based masks (using `CAShapeLayer`) or to invert images, this is not what I am looking for. I do not want to invert a path mask or an image but a view mask.

Assume the `view` is a red rect and the `mask` is a green circle. Applying the `mask` to the `view` would result in a red circle. However, I would like to create a red rect with a circle hole in it.

**Again:** Creating a circle path and applying it as mask is no problem. I am **NOT** looking for path masks (inverted or not) but for a solution to use **any UIView as inverted mask**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on what you mean by *"any `UIView`"* and *"inverted"*.

For example... if this is `anyView`:

[image]

What is ***inverted***?

Let's assume that you're talking about a `UIView` with a **clear** background, containing some subviews and maybe some shapes, etc.

So, if we setup a label with lots of large text that will be behind our views:

[image]

then add an image view that we want to mask, our `anyView`, and another copy of `anyView` with clear background so we can see what we're doing:

[image]

What we can do is render `anyView` to a `UIImage` (`renderedImage`), then create another `UIImage` with a solid color (can be any solid color, I used `.systemGreen` for this example), and then render `renderedImage` with `blendMode: .destinationOut`, to get this:

[image]

Then we'll create a new `UIImageView` with that image, and use **that** as the mask:

```
func mask(someView: UIView, withView: UIView) {
    
    // make sure the background of the view we're going to use
    //  as the mask is clear
    let bkgColor = withView.backgroundColor
    withView.backgroundColor = .clear
    
    let sz = withView.bounds.size
    
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: sz)
    
    let renderedImage = renderer.image { rendererContext in
        withView.drawHierarchy(in: withView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    
    let invertedImage = renderer.image { rendererContext in
        UIColor.systemGreen.setFill()
        UIRectFill(.init(origin: .zero, size: renderedImage.size))
        renderedImage.draw(at: .zero, blendMode: .destinationOut, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
    tempImageView.image = invertedImage
    
    // create a new image view to use as a mask
    let newMaskView = UIImageView(frame: someView.bounds)
    newMaskView.image = invertedImage
    someView.mask = newMaskView
    
    // reset the mask source view's background
    withView.backgroundColor = bkgColor
    
}
```

giving us this result:

[image]